# Why does $form_state['values'] get obliterated in drupal_process_form()?

Tags: drupal, cck

I'm trying to programmatically store CCK type nodes using drupal_execute(). Empty nodes get created; none of the CCK fields is saved. Evidently the first line in drupal_process_form() is responsible:

```
$form_state['values'] = array();
```

So my question is why does 'values' get erased, and more importantly, how can I save CCK fields using drupal_execute()?

I tried save_node() too which worked well; however I'd prefer the former since it invokes validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values array gets cleared in `drupal_process_form()` because it will be populated from the `$_POST` global later on. If you take a look at [`drupal_execute()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_execute/6), you will see that it does the opposite, that is, populating the `$_POST` global from the passed in `$form_state['values']`.

I think this is done to allow the form processing to work the same way as it would for a 'normal' form submit, so `drupal_execute` mainly sets the stage so that everything looks more or less the same as with a 'normal' submit later on.

This means that your approach is basically correct and should work - if it doesn't, there must be something else going wrong. I can not guess what this might be, but you could check [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/178506#comment-895418) for some discussions on your approach, and the CCK field topic specifically (it is a mixed thread discussing the `node_save()` approach as well, but the linked part might fit your specific situation).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I've come across that thread before; it's been helpful. I'm dealing with over 200 fields in a single type (this is just a prototype, it should be normalized eventually) at the moment, and it's rather difficult to locate the culprit. I noticed that form_get_errors() emits messages regarding only the standard fields such as title; is there perhaps a different way to extract validation errors?

Comment: @Stan: There is no different way that I know of. Are you sure it's not just a timing (weight) issue, i.e. that your call to `form_get_errors()` occurs before CCKs validation functions where called?

Comment: Well `form_get_errors()` is called right after `drupal_execute()`. I'll use `node_save()` for now or until the number of fields becomes more manageable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was confused about the same thing. Wish there was a comment explaining the line!